# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' using dataset for values

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to do a Bar graph where I can see the 3 medals of a country. I've already dropped all the teams I only have one but when I do it I get this error...
This is what I got:

```py
N = 3
ind = np.arange(N) 
width = 0.25

goldMedals = df[(df.Medal == 'Gold')]
bar1 = plt.bar(ind, goldMedals, width, color = 'gold')
  
silverMedals = df[(df.Medal == 'Silver')]
bar2 = plt.bar(ind+width, silverMedals, width, color='bronze')
  
bronzeMedals = df[(df.Medal == 'Bronze')]
bar3 = plt.bar(ind+width*2, bronzeMedals, width, color = 'b')
  
plt.xlabel("Medal")
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title("Medal Portugal")
  
plt.xticks(ind+width,['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Silver'])
plt.legend( (bar1, bar2, bar3), ('Gold', 'Bronze', 'Silver') )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error in your question (formatted as code).

Comment: Note: I think Pandas has this type of plot already built-in, and otherwise Seaborn will have a convenient variant.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing since you have not presented any data, but I think you are trying to visualize the results of conditional extraction in a long form data frame. The cause of the error is that the extraction result is a data frame, but the index and the data frame itself are specified respectively. So, for each graph, the index and y-axis value of the data frame are specified.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
 nation  medal  count
0 "South Korea" gold 24
1 China  gold  10
2 Canada  gold  9
3 "South Korea"  silver  13
4  China  silver  15
5  Canada  silver  12
6  "South Korea"  bronze  11
7  China  bronze  8
8  Canada  bronze  12
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.query('nation == "Canada"')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 3
ind = np.arange(N) 
width = 0.25

goldMedals = df[df.medal == 'gold']
bar1 = plt.bar(goldMedals.medal, goldMedals['count'], width, color='gold')

silverMedals = df[(df.medal == 'silver')]
bar2 = plt.bar(silverMedals.medal, silverMedals['count'], width, color='gray')
  
bronzeMedals = df[(df.medal == 'bronze')]
bar3 = plt.bar(bronzeMedals.medal, bronzeMedals['count'], width, color='brown')
  
plt.xlabel("Medal")
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title("Medal Canada")
  
#plt.xticks(ind+width,['Gold', 'Silver','Bronze'])
plt.legend((bar1, bar2, bar3), ('Gold', 'Bronze', 'Silver'))
plt.show()
```

[image]